# Problema con variacion de DFS - C#

Tags: c#

Tengo un problema con una variacion de un DFS el cual tiene hayar TODOS LOS VERTICES A UNA DISTANCIA DADA DEL VERTICE ORIGEN, para esto utilize un algoritmo de DFS el cual busca todos los posibles caminos dados un vertice origen y un vertice destino, para reciclar codigo coloco el origen en la seccion del paramentro destino y con un recorro todos lo vertices colocandolos como parametro origen en el metodo, a esto le agrego una suma de distancias y cuando cumple la dos condiciones muestra un resultado es decir cuando alcanza el destino + x distancia devuelve ese resultado , mi problema es que aveces no otorga el resultado correcto y no se por que...

```
 static void DFS_S2(vertice origen, vertice destino, grafo graf,float distancia, float suma, string path)
    {
        path = (path == String.Empty ? path : $"{path},") + origen.nombre;

        if (origen.nombre == destino.nombre&distancia==suma)
        {
            string[] datos2 = path.Split(new char[] { ',' });

           Console.WriteLine(datos2[0]);
        }

        else
        {
            for (int con = 0; con < origen.adyacencias.Length; con++)
            {
                var visitado = Regex.IsMatch(path, $@"\b{graf.vertices[con].nombre}\b");
                if (origen.adyacencias[con] > 0 && !visitado)
                {
                    suma = suma + origen.adyacencias[con];
                    DFS_S2(graf.vertices[con], destino, graf, distancia, suma, path);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hola Shiki, ¿podrías compartir el código de construcción del grafo donde tienes el problema? A primera vista no veo ningún error en tu código. Si se me ocurren algunos casos que podrían dar problemas. Por ejemplo si existe un vértice con nombre `nodo1` y está en el `path`, cuando compruebes si se han visitado los vértices con nombre `nodo11`, `nodo12` o `minodo1.a` te devolverá un resultado positivo. Sin embargo no es posible saber si el problema puede venir de ahí sin ver cómo construyes el grafo y los datos con los que estás obteniendo los errores.

Answer (score 0):

En el codigo me parece que en la linea donde realizas la condición:

```
if (origen.nombre == destino.nombre&distancia==suma)
```

En lugar de un solo *&* (que realiza AND bit a bit) deberías utilizar doble *&*, lo que sería:

```
if (origen.nombre == destino.nombre && distancia==suma)
```

Aunque también deberías considerar que si deseas encontrar todos los vértices a una distancia dada de un vertice ***v*** es más recomendable usar BFS ya que este te da la distancia mínima a la que se encuentran todos los vértices de un grafo de un vértice ***v*** del propio grafo.